# Multidimensional array in PHP for SOAP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create the following array in PHP for a SOAP call:

[image: Picture of the array]

I have tried to make the array myself but I am stuck at this piece of code:

```
$params = array(
"ReportId" => xxxxx,
"Parameters" =>  array( // <-- This array should be in 'Parameter' 
                "Name" => "xxxxx",
                "Value" => "xxxxx"
                )   
);

$client->__soapCall("Get", array("securityKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "parms" => $params));
```

As you can see here I need to create an array within 'Parameter' containing the 'Name' and the 'Value', this 'Parameter' should be in 'Parameters'.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the value in `Parameter` key, you can write the array like this

```
$params = array(
  "ReportId" => xxxxx,
  "Parameters" => array(
    'Parameter' => array(
       "Name" => "xxxxx",
       "Value" => "xxxxx"
     )   
  )
);
```